Playwright test fails because of Mapbox and LineAwesome
I have a Svelte application that interact with Mapbox-gl and Line-Awesome. I'm defining a test suite for that using Playwright. My playwright configuration is:
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
    // Dirs
    testDir: './test',
    outputDir: './test/out',

    // Run Setup
    fullyParallel: true,
    reporter: [
        ['html'],
        ['json', {  outputFile: 'test-results.json' }],
    ],

    // Setup Assertions Timeout
    expect: {
        timeout: 10000,
    },

    use: {
        baseURL: 'http://localhost/test/home',
        headless: true,

        // Recording Options
        trace: 'on-first-retry',
        video: 'on-first-retry',
        screenshot: 'only-on-failure',

        // Miscellaneous
        acceptDownloads: true,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        bypassCSP: true,
    },
});

Then I defined two tests:
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

const users = [
    { userId: 'fake.user@randomdomain.com', userRole: 'AdminUser' },
    { userId: 'fake.user@randomdomain.com', userRole: 'AuthorizedUser' },
    { userId: 'fake.user@randomdomain.com', userRole: 'CompanyUser' },
];

test.describe.parallel('ShareViewTest', () => {
    users.forEach(({ userId: generatorId, userRole: generatorRole }) => {
        users.forEach(({ userId: openerId, userRole: openerRole }) => {
            /*
            if (generatorId == openerId && generatorRole == openerRole){
                test.skip()
            }*/
            if(generatorId == ''){
                return
            }
            else{
                test(`From (${generatorId}, ${generatorRole}) to (${openerId}, ${openerRole})`, async ({ browser }) => {
                    let generatorContex = await browser.newContext();
                    let openerContext = await browser.newContext();
    
                    let generatorPage = await generatorContex.newPage();
                    await generatorPage.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
                        'X-Test-User': generatorId,
                        'X-Test-Role': generatorRole,
                    });
    
                    await generatorPage.goto('');
                    await generatorPage.waitForSelector('.mapboxgl-canvas');
                    await generatorPage.waitForTimeout(5000)
                    // Hack for fly animation
                    await generatorPage.waitForTimeout(1000);
                    await generatorPage.getByTitle('Share View').click();
    
                    const linkArea = generatorPage.getByTestId('share-link');
                    const shareLink = await linkArea.inputValue();
    
                    // Step 2: Open link as second user
                    let openerPage = await openerContext.newPage();
                    await openerPage.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
                        'X-Test-User': openerId,
                        'X-Test-Role': openerRole,
                    });
    
                    await openerPage.goto(shareLink);
                    await openerPage.waitForSelector('.mapboxgl-canvas');
                    await openerPage.waitForTimeout(5000)

                    // Hack for fly animation
                    await openerPage.waitForTimeout(1000);
                    await openerPage.getByTitle('Share View').click();
    
                    const newLinkAread = openerPage.getByTestId('share-link');
                    const newShareLink = await newLinkAread.inputValue();
    
                    if (generatorId == openerId || ['AdminUser', 'AuthorizedUser'].includes(openerId)) {
                        expect(newShareLink).toBe(shareLink);
                    } else {
                        expect(newShareLink).not.toBe(shareLink)!;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

and
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

const userRoles = ['AdminUser', 'AuthorizedUser', 'CompanyUser'];
const testID = 'AAAAAA-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDD';

const makeRandomString = () => {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter < 10) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        counter += 1;
    }
    return result;
};

test.describe.parallel('ModifyInfoTest', () => {
    userRoles.forEach((role) => {
        test(`As ${role}`, async ({ browser }) => {
            let context = await browser.newContext();
            let userPage = await context.newPage();
            await userPage.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
                'X-Test-Role': role,
            });
            await userPage.goto('');
            await userPage.goto(`#/seq/${testID}`);
            await userPage.waitForLoadState('networkidle')
            await userPage.waitForTimeout(5000)
            await userPage.getByTestId(`analysis-${testID}`).isVisible();
            const fieldTestId = '[data-testid="seqinfo-user"]';
            const isInputField = await userPage.evaluate((selector) => {
                const element = document.querySelector(selector);
                return element && element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input';
            }, fieldTestId);

            if (role == 'CompanyUser') {
                expect(isInputField).toBeFalsy();
            } else {
                await userPage.getByTestId('seqinfo-user').click();
                await userPage.getByTestId('seqinfo-user').fill(`${makeRandomString()}@companydomain.com`);
            }

            // Modifying Location
            await userPage.getByTestId('seqinfo-location').click();
            await userPage.getByTestId('seqinfo-location').fill(makeRandomString());

            // Modifying Description
            await userPage.getByTestId('seqinfo-description').click();
            await userPage.getByTestId('seqinfo-description').fill(makeRandomString());
            await userPage.waitForLoadState('networkidle')
            await userPage.waitForTimeout(5000)

            await expect(userPage.getByTestId('update-button')).toBeVisible();
        });
    });
});


The first is failing because when I initialize the map in my app with:
map = new mapbox.Map({
    container: mapContainer,
    accessToken: config.mapboxAccessToken,
    style: getStyleURL(queryInitStyle),
    center: [0, 20],
    zoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 26,
    attributionControl: false,
    logoPosition: 'bottom-right',
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
    testMode: isTestingEnv,
});

the operation sometimes is slightly delayed and when I get the link through mapContainer.getQueryString() it may differ.  This method simply returns a query for mabox view parameters in order to zoom on the same point (and it works, manually tested multiple times).
The second fails because the icon where I should click on is not visible. The icond would be:
<h2
    class="info-title__link no-print"
    title="Update"
    
    style="visibility: {toUpdate}"
    on:click={updateInfo}
>
    <i class="las la-sync" data-testid="update-button"/>
</h2>

and the icons are loaded in index.html with:
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css"
/>

As you can see, in the first tests I tried different wait functions but the test is still flaky. For the second, the icons are never loaded (in general) and so the expect.toBeVisible() is always false. How do I solve those?
I tried to test svelte app with playwright but it fails loading icons and map from linew-awesome and mapbox
